# Error in Publishing InfoPath Form downloaded from SharePoint Server

Tags: .net, sharepoint, infopath, infopath-forms-services

I am new to InfoPath!
i have downloaded a InfoPath Form from Sharepoint and trying to publish the InfoPath Form it displays Error as follows:

```
Error:InfoPath will remove the following fields from your SharePoint list:
field1; field2; Middle Name

InfoPath will add the following fields to your SharePoint list:
field1; field2

Column settings in SharePoint will be updated to match the field properties set in InfoPath. Any modifications made on the server after the form was opened might be lost.
```

Why this Error Occurs while publishing the copy without making changes?

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is a promoted column in the original site collection the InfoPath form came from and this column (field) doesn't exist in the site collection you are currently trying to publish too.

Try adding the field to the site collection you are publishing the form too.

Comment: Thanks @Meyer Denney for replying! i have checked the site collection the Middle Name Field EXISTS in List! but still the error occurs while publishing! any suggestion?